# How do I heal outside of battle in Hunted: The Demon's Forge?

Tags: hunted-the-demons-forge

I may have missed this part during the tutorial and now I can't figure out how to use a potion outside of battle. I'm usually at pretty low health after a fight (I favor melee to ranged) so I'm dying at the very beginning of the next enemy encounter.

Is there a button to heal outside of battle? Also, do I have to wait for my partner to heal me during combat or can I do it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using health potions is done by **R** key,worked for me no matter the combat status.Plus the health potion capacity and health points are increases by overall kills(you+partner).

Restoration potions(potions around players waist) can only be used to revive other player,done by **space**.After you have revived or been revived enough times the capacity of the bottle increases to maximum of 3 (11 revives needed).